# ReferenceError: event is not defined in mozila firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

This code is not working for me in Firefox(V21.0) but works in IE(V9,V10) and Chrome (V 27.0.1453.110 m)

Method cal:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" class="search-bar-input"
                         onkeyup="handleKeyPress('btn1');">
```

Method definition:

```
function handleKeyPress(searchButtonId) {
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    alert(event.KeyCode);
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined
> if (event.keyCode === 13) {

Does anyone have any idea to solve the issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" class="search-bar-input" onkeyup="handleKeyPress(event, 'btn1');">
```

Then

```
function handleKeyPress(event) {
    event = event || window.event //For IE
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        alert(event.keyCode);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T9x9L/)

Comment: @Arun_C_C it is because in IE enter key forces page reload instead of onkeyup try onkeypress http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T9x9L/2/

Comment: Not working in Firefox 50.1.0

Answer (score 2):

You could store the `btn1` parameter as a `data-*` attribute and use unobtrusive Javascript to assign the event handler (instead of inline).

Also your line `alert(event.KeyCode);` is wrong, the `K` in `KeyPress` should be lowercase `k`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QpL8y/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" class="search-bar-input" data-searchButtonId="btn1" />
```

Javascript:

```
function handleKeyPress(event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log(event.keyCode + this.getAttribute("data-searchButtonId"));
   }
}

window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById("txt1").onkeyup = handleKeyPress;   
}
```